# Laravel 8 notification primary key migration error

Tags: database-migration, laravel-8, mysql-8.0

I have just updated to MySQL 8 and Laravel 8.12, and I use Laravel standard notification on my system. Before I upgraded my Mysql 5.7 to 8 (test environment), I had no problem with migration, but not its complaints.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3750 Unable to create or change a
> table without a primary key, when the system variable
> 'sql_require_primary_key' is set. Add a primary key to the table or
> unset this variable to avoid this message. Note that tables without a
> primary key can cause performance problems in row-based replication,
> so please consult your DBA before changing this setting. (SQL: create
> table `notifications` (`id` char(36) not null, `type` varchar(255) not
> null, `notifiable_type` varchar(255) not null, `notifiable_id` bigint
> unsigned not null, `data` text not null, `read_at` timestamp null,
> `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default
> character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

But in my migration, there is a primary key specified as it does from the notification standard migration.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->morphs('notifiable');
        $table->text('data');
        $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: In your `config/database.php` try to set `'strict' => false,`. I had a similar problem once and this fixed it. After the migration you could it set back to true. Beware that MySQL in strict mode is really strict. That is certainly true for updates.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
$table->increments('id');
```

Comment: That will not work, because id already exist
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
And the ID is an uuid

Comment: I mean replace `$table->uuid('id')->primary()` by `$table->increments('id')`. Is that meet with your needs?

Answer (score -1):

1-try `$table->increments('id');`
2-try `php artisan migrate:rollback`
3-try `php artisan migrate:refresh`

but be careful you will lost your data in your database